# Scrolling continuously without user interaction

Tags: react-native, react-native-scrollview

Is there a way to scroll ScrollView **programmatically** to achieve an animation similar to ticker shown below?

[image: the truax ticker]

So far I have tried using `scrollToOffset` with `setInterval` but the animation looks laggy (due to the animation completion duration and interval firing speed). It would be helpful to know when scroll is about to finish, or calling a callback function when `scrollToOffset` is completed. But neither of them seems to be possible.

Comment: Can you provide a code sample and add information about what version of React Native you are using?

Comment: Version 0.48, code is just scrollview with ref to invoke its function with an interval. Nothing fancy

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'd have to see the code to provide help however.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe take a look at [react-native-text-ticker](https://github.com/deanhet/react-native-text-ticker)? It doesn't use FlatList but it has a nice animated text scroll.